# Splitting video camera source so 2 applications can access, on Windows

Tags: video, directshow, webcam

I need to access a video camera simultaneously in 2 applications. I have found some solutions, such as WebcamSplitter and Splitcam, but I don't want an application - I want something that can be integrated into my application, and controlled via some sort of API or configuration file.

Here's a usage scenario:

Split video source name = Video Splitter

Camera 1 name = Logitech Webcam

Camera 2 name = Osprey video

2 applications, A and B, show previews of the video source. A (in our control) and B (3rd party application that we can configure and launch) are configured to use Video Splitter as the video source. Initially, before any source is configured for Video Splitter, it might display a default image. Application A configures Video Splitter to use Logitech Webcam as the video source. Both applications now show previews of the Logitech Webcam. Application A then configures Video Splitter to use Osprey video as the source; now, both applications show previews of the Osprey video source.

Does anyone know any existing solutions (ie: DirectShow filters?) that do this? Ideally, we would not want any 3rd party applications to launch to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in DirectShow you can have two apps accessing the same "source" (filter) at the same time.  So dual-app should work. If not then creating two separate graphs might work. Dunno.

Comment: Ok looks like there are a few apps out there that allow you to do this. http://betterlogic.com/roger/2013/05/directshow-webcam-splitter/